# How to make content show/hide depending on device

Tags: html, css, email, media

I'm looking for a way to show/hide content for an email newsletter based on the device the customer is opening the email on.

I've currently got this snippet of code in the head section:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #mobile { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
#normal { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  #mobile { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
  #normal { display: block; }  /* show it on large screens */
}
```

Along with:

```
<div id="mobile">content</div> or <div id="normal">content1<div>
```

This works fine if I was using it for web, I can scale my browser window and content appears/disappears based on the width of the window, but as soon as I send a test through our email system it works fine on mobile but breaks down on desktop (Gmail).

And because this is an email I can't utilise javascript so it all needs to be html/css.

Anything I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that many email clients have very primitive HTML and CSS support, so it might not actually be possible on some clients. Sorry I can't help more though.

Comment: There's some information here about which standards are supported by Gmail: http://www.email-standards.org/clients/gmail/ and http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. Showing and hiding content in html email newsletters was eluding me for ages!

```
/* Hide on Desktop */

.hide-desktop { 
    /* non-gmail */
    display: none; 

    /* gmail */
    font-size: 0; 
    max-height: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 

    /* outlook */
    mso-hide: all;

    /* optional, required only if you're using padding */
    padding: 0; 

}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .hide-desktop {
        display: block !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        line-height: 1.5 !important;
    }
}


/* Hide on Mobile */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .hide-mobile {
        display: none;
        max-height: 0; 
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Don't forget to inline the `.hide-desktop` rule, that is outside of the media query.

So using media queries and a number of hacks we can do a bullish hide all for desktop and then undo it media queries. Inversely, because mobile clients have decent support for media queries, we can hide the mobile content with media queries alone. The outlier, gmail, just gets the desktop view – which is unfortunate but still useable.